# Deb packages on MacOS

Tags: wine, steam

I've been trying to run steam, and more specifically Saints Row 3 on my MacBook air, to no avail. I was wondering if there was a way to install Deb packages on Mac so I could run a Linux version of steam? Sort of like Wine.

Comment: What makes you think that hacking your system to run a game in Steam within Wine based on Debian packages is easier than fixing whatever problems you had with running the game within the macOS version of Steam?

Comment: If you want to run Linux, get a VM (e.g. VirtualBox) and proceed from there.

Comment: Saints Row is not officially supported on MacOS. This seemed like an easier way to go than finding a new computer.

Comment: I did try dual booting Ubuntu, but I had problems with the built-in graphics (Intel HD 4000 and opengl 4.1 apparently don't play nice.)

Comment: Booting into Linux will not turn the built-in graphics into a GeForce GT 630 or Radeon HD 685 (which seems to be the minimum for the game) :-)

Comment: It might not run well, but I'm hoping it'll at least work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install/run Debian packages natively, the kernel and a lot of required data structures are vastly different. Usually people who want to run Linux code

- set up a VM and install Linux within in. VirtualBox is a (good) cost-free solution here, there are also Parallels and VMware which offer more features but aren't free
- install Linux in a second partition and dual-boot either Linux or macOS. Install instructions depend on Mac hardware, macOS version and Linux distribution.

Neither way will compensate for underpowered hardware though (the graphics to run the game in your case).

Comment: While not the answer I was looking for, I suppose you're not wrong. Thanks for the help.